# What does title "Cost Effective Web Design" signify in English?

Tags: antonyms, typography, professions, business-language

When addressing on search engines or even writing an email about a business query for a cheap web designer does the statement pass on the message clearly "[Cost Effective Web Design](http://www.egochi.com)" or Should I use a one liner which is more direct like "[Affordable Web Designer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JbKlSL0RyU)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both correct and effective.

Because the first one refers only to the design and not to you, subjectively I sense that I'm talking to a "company" and not a person, which has its positives and negatives. The second one, however, sounds like an individual.

Both paint the seller as providing web design services for a good price.